# how to open OpenStreetmap in mkmapview? -iphone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, openstreetmap

I have gone through certain related answers but dont seem to get correct answer or the answer I need.

As we open googlemap in mkmap view I want to open openstreet map in mkmapview.

If there is any link or sample code showing it please pass it on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MKMapView conforms to Google Map terms and conditions so it uses only google map. You cant integrate OpenStreetMap just like that into MKMapView. Google code has a API [RouteME](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) which renders OpenStreetMap in iphone.

RouteMe also provide a good documentation how to include into our project. So feel free to use that.

Comment: To future visitors, this answer no longer applies.

Answer (score 3):

Import these Frameworks:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Include this delegate

```
@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Add this code to your preexisting viewDidLoad method

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Tile system URL template goes here
    NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"; 

    // Associating overlay with URL template
    MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template]; 

    // Allowing overlays on MKMapView & disabling Apple map data
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES; 

    // Adding overlay to MKMapView above Apple lables
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];

    // Linking the delegate to allow the next method to be called
    self.mapView.delegate = self; 
}
```

And this somewhere in your class that’s mapView’s delegate (most likely a view controller).

```
(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay 
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKTileOverlay class]]) {
        // Overlay the tile with the new template
        return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay]; 
    }
    return nil;
}
```